# Android Studio Logcat Search

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-logcat, android-studio-3.0

I am facing a strange problem with android studio. In logcat monitor, there is not much space for search box. I am not able to find out any option to make it larger.

[image]

is there any way to make this larger?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to increase the width. However, I instead used Filters to setup my frequently used search queries.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the problem is with the device name, which is too long and due to this it squeezes the Logcat search. So to the solution I got for this name issue is to change the device name (whether its Genymotion or AVD). So to change your device name follow below steps :

**For AVD :** Go to **Tools** --> **Android** --> **AVD Manager** --> Select your device and then change the device name to shorter one.

**For Genymotion :** Open you **VirtualBox** --> Select your device and then Click on **Settings** --> Change the name to shorter one.

And other option is Right click on **Logcat** tab and then enable **Floating mode**. Then just resize the floating window so that the Logcat search can expand.

**Edit:** You can also use CTRL+F to filter logcat. It will open new search bar and then you can try on that.

Answer (score 1):

For quickly search, use universal key combination CTRL+F.

Comment: have try with right mouse click on logcat and choose to show window in floating mode. Your problem is low screen resolution at your display

Comment: Yes, the resolution is the problem, but there must be a way to solve this. I have tried floating mode with every other option available in logcat window but nothing worked.