# How to enlarge Logcat search text field in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

The text field for search in Android Studio on my laptop (15-inch diagonal) is too small. I barely able to type anything on it.

[image: Small Screen]

I move Android Studio to a larger monitor and I'm able to see the whole text field.

[image: Large Screen]

I think it's ridiculous to have a text field this small for such an important feature. And a 15-inch monitor is large enough for a text field.

Is there a way to enlarge this text field?

Edit:

- Shorten device name doesn't work. I'm using LG G4 and its still small.

[image: shorten device name]

Comment: Apparently floating mode is the only solution for now.

Comment: by looking at your image it seems your monitor resolution needs to be adjusted or your connected device has a low resolution.

Comment: Your phone name in the logcat is very large, try changing the phone name to short one

Comment: @SonuSanjeev doesn't work, I have updated the question

Comment: @NabinBhandari would you post an answer for that?

Comment: @aldok Did you try restarting the studio after changing the name, i still had that long name in the drop down tray and when i restarted the studio the issue was gone.

Comment: @aldok See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615551/android-studio-logcat-search/48424527#48424527)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone name in the logcat is very large. Try changing the name of the phone to a short one.

If you are using an emulator try :

Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager and edit the phone name to a shorter name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem, use **Floating Mode** for the logcat tab. Then you can resize the whole window slightly so that the text field will grow.

You can enable floating mode by right clicking the logcat tab or left clicking the settings gear icon.

I am using Android studio 3.0.1 and do not see this problem in 15" laptop. If you are using Android studio 3.0.0, update it.